# what is the proper design for calling controller methods?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a controller that calls several methods of an external SOAP api and returns some data, for example

```
public class ExternalApplicationController {
    @Autowired
    private ExternalApplicationSoapService soapService;

    public FirstResponse getFirst() {
        return soapService.getFirst()
    }

    public SecondResponse getSecond() {
        return soapService.getSecond()
    }

    public ThirdResponse getThird() {
        return soapService.getThird()
    }

    ...
}
```

Everything was clear before the client asked to process exceptions on each method call. Now any method of my controller can get SOAPFaultException, so i need to modify each method with a try / catch block like this:

```
...
public FirstResponse getFirst() {
    try {
        return soapService.getFirst()
    catch (SOAPFaultException ex){
        // do something similar for all methods
    }
}
....
```

I guess i should use a generified utility class that handles the common logic, but i suppose that design principles would be broken in that way... There shouldn't be anything between controller and service by MVC...

Also it's not very natural to make a service that should call soapService because all his methods would duplicate logic... And I don't want to write try / catch at each controller method, because it's a clear code duplicate..

Is there any suitable pattern for this?

Comment: ExceptionHandler and ControllerAdvice are possible options.

Comment: Not in my case. The project includes multiple external soap services. Using ControllerAdvice & ExceptionHandler i'll grab all of them accidently...

Comment: I'm not sure your ExternalApplicationController even *is* a Controller in the MVC sense? And I wouldn't be too worried about having the try-catch block in every method. You could, of course, declare the exception via `throws` and then handle it in a proxy class that uses reflection, or stuff like that, but that might be brutally overkill. Personally, I'd just write a `SoapFaultHandler` class or something like that and invoke `SoapFaultHandler.getInstance().handle(e)` in each of the methods.